# Develop WSGI App In IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, wsgi, jupyter-notebook

When developing a WSGI application with, for example, [falcon](http://falconframework.org/), in order to test requests you need to host the application with, for example, [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), working from .py files in a directory.  Then you can curl the localhost from the command line to test responses.

Is there a way, instead, to develop the application in an IPython Notebook, executing application commands in notebook and then testing from the command line (or in notebook)?

For example, say the IPython Notebook is working on Tornado at localhost:8888, is it possible to exploit that same server to expose the application in development at a different port?

Is there any way to accomplish this?  Maybe I just love using IPython Notebook too much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a WSGI application you can use WebTest as an internal client. That is, rather than needing a WSGI server, WebTest can test direct against the WSGI application entry point within the same process. Can't provide link right now, so search for 'Python WebTest'.